# Saving printer properties in XE4 c++ VCL application

Tags: c++, printing, c++builder-xe4

I am trying to save some of the printer properties (ie page size) to an ini file in the following way:

```
    Printer()->PrinterIndex = Printer()->PrinterIndex;    

    wchar_t printerDevice[256], printerDriver[256], printerPort[256];
    THandle printerDeviceModeHandle = 0;
    DEVMODE *printerDeviceMode;

    Printer()->GetPrinter(printerDevice, printerDriver, printerPort, printerDeviceModeHandle);

    if (printerDeviceModeHandle != 0)
    {

        DEVMODE *printerDeviceMode = (DEVMODE *) GlobalLock((void *)printerDeviceModeHandle);

        if ((printerDeviceMode != NULL) && (printerDeviceMode->dmFields & DM_PAPERSIZE))                
            ini->WriteInteger("PrintingPage", "PaperSize", printerDeviceMode->dmPaperSize);

        GlobalUnlock((void *)printerDeviceModeHandle);
    }
```

The code gets within the inner if statement but When I inspect the `printerDeviceMode` variable only the `dmDeviceName` appears to be correct. Many of the other settings appear to be garbage (including `dmPaperSize`):

[image: Image of debug inspector window for printerDeviceMode]

Note that `dmSize` is 0.

I have tried changing the page size for the printer using a TPrinterSetupDialog components but the value of `dmPaperSize` stays the same.

Have I missed a step somewhere?

This is a XE4 c++ builder VCL project.